# USB device, connecting via IP, virtual USB

Tags: windows-10, windows-server-2016

I have a server without USB ports, so I bought a USB-to-IP device (TP Link TL-PS310). Is it possible, in any way, to connect the IP-Device (IP 172.16.40.12) to a virtual USB port in MS Windows Server?

I want to connect multiple USB Card readers to the server, so the software (which only checks USB ports) can read the cards.

Comment: I think what you have is a printer server. No, it won't give you a "virtual USB", it should behave like any other networked computer sharing a printer and eventually a mass storage device.

Comment: Not sure what the TL-PS310 actually does, but have a look at [usbip](http://usbip.sourceforge.net). It has a windows client, and USB devices will appear as virtual USB ports in Windows. If the TL-PS310 isn't using `usbip`, you'll need some other hardware where you can install the server part of `usbip`, for example a RaspPi.

Comment: Any other suggestion to connect 4 USB Cardreader to the Windows Server?
The software installed on WS only checks the USB ports. And the hardware doesn't has any USB port. Connecting USB via Network seemed to be a good solution ...

Comment: Do you have access to the hardware ? If yes, you can use a PCIe card to USB slots